# How can I explain to people that the phrase “off of ” is grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, phrasal-verbs, off-of

How can I explain to people that the phrase *off of* is grammatically incorrect?

I‘ve heard this phrase used a lot, especially by Americans (though they aren't the only ones).

In my understanding, *off of* should usually be replaced by *off*, as in,

> I took the book *off* the shelf

as opposed to

> I took the book *off of* the shelf

Am I wrong?  Or is there perhaps some simple way I can explain this to most people?

Comment: Isn't *take off* the phrase here, which might cause some confusion?

Comment: It's similar to the use of "write me" as opposed to "write to me". As a non-American English speaker "write me" means to write the word "me" whereas "write to me" means to write something for me.

Comment: In America the use of "off of", "waiting on (a friend?)" and pronouncing the "t" in "often", is now commonly heard from broadcasters and not edited out of many newspapers. Either the users are not taught as we were in journalism school or it is, indeed, a mark of affiliation. The current trend is to be of-the-people. Erudition is out, elitism is meant to be muffled in favor of being like the common man. When broadcasters and other journalists uphold this trend, of course we will have more questions like these! I don't believe it's in the vein same as "don't forget to write me".

Comment: @Francesca I'm about as elitist as they come, and I resent being told by narrow-minded rationalizers that I may not employ the language of Shakespeare and Shaw.

Comment: I don't think, on the other hand, that _I'm looking out the window_ is allowed in British English: the prepositional use of _out_ is confined (traditionally) to other English-speaking areas. These anomalies are given prominence by the fact that we're nowadays communicating virtually instantaneously over the web.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have heard _out the window_ many times, from AE and BE speakers.

Comment: @Francesca What's wrong with pronouncing the 't' in often?  This reminds me of a passage in Steven Pinker's book concerning a a Massachusetts controversy in which some legislators were upset that their kids were being taught by teachers with a foreign accent.  A local parent responded with the observation that her kid's Bay State teacher taught the kid that 'orphan' was a homonym for 'often.'

Comment: @Merk: it's inconsistent with the way most people pronounce "soften," listen, epistle" etc. So it's seen by some as an erroneous attempt to pronounce every letter in a word where regular sound change historically caused the /t/ to be eliminated (like pronouncing the "t" in "ballet").

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't know how you can explain to people in general that it's grammatically incorrect, but here is one idea: when you go to a James Brown tribute concert and the singer says "Get up offa that thing" what you could do is to trounce the security guards, climb on to the stage, pounce onto the singer, grab the microphone and say "In fact you should be saying not 'get up offa that thing' but 'get up off that thing' since 'offa' is grammatically incorrect." I'm sure everyone will thank you for your grammatical corrections.

Being serious for a moment though, it's very difficult to decide what is or is not "grammatically correct". E.g. in the UK we say "outside my house" but US people often say "outside of my house". How can you actually decide which of these two is grammatically correct? Unfortunately it's not possible since English grammar is not a science like physics but merely a description of what people actually do, and that has changed very significantly over the years. If I was teaching someone English I would definitely say "off" is correct and "off of" is wrong, but this kind of decision is based on intuition, based on the usages of educated native speakers.

Comment: Consider "off [of]" for trans-Atlantic communications.

Answer (score 53):

*How can I explain to people that the phrase "off of" is grammatically incorrect?*

You can't, because it's not.

There are thousands of examples of “off of” in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/), not just in spoken English, but in magazines, newspapers, and academic journals as well. “Off of” is well-established as standard in American English. Plain “off” may be stylistically preferable in many cases, but it is simply not a rule of English grammar that if a word *could* be removed it *must* be removed. Some people seem to think that such a rule exists. It does not.

Comment: @a_m0d, in that case I guess the answer to your original question is to decry it as one of those barbarous Americanisms, and then you can ride the lift down from your flat and walk across the car park to your car so you can put your biscuits into the boot, and be careful not to hit your tyres on the kerb as you speed away on the wrong side of the road.

Comment: Don't forget that barbarous proto-American, Shakespeare (Henry VI pt II, act 2 scene 1).

Comment: there is no evidence from any poster here that it is an Americanism, and has been used my many Brits and non-Americans

Comment: I used to use this phrase. I looked it up and stopped, but as I continue to encounter it I keep checking again... Eh, I will just take both as fine, but avoid it myself. Johnson's General History (1724): "Two days afterwards they chased a sloop of 60 tons, and took her two leagues off of Cape Henry;"

Answer (score 28):

The phrase "off of" has a long history, which, according to the OED, stretches back roughly 500 years.  If you want to consider it to be "wrong", then it certainly has a lot of staying power.  Here are their quotations using "off of":

> ?**c1450** in G. Müller Aus mittelengl.
>   Medizintexten (1929) 116 Take a
>   sponfull of e licour..of of e fyir and
>   sette it in good place tyl at it be ny
>   colde, soo as ou mayst suffryn to
>   holdyn er-in in hand.
>   **a1616**
>   SHAKESPEARE Henry VI, Pt. 2 (1623) II.
>   i. 98 A fall off of [**1594** Falling off
>   on] a Tree.
>   **1667** A. MARVELL Corr. in
>   Wks. (1875) II. 224 The Lords and we
>   cannot yet get off of the difficultyes
>   risen betwixt us.
>   **1678** J. BUNYAN
>   Pilgrim's Progress 49 About a furlong
>   off of the Porters Lodge. 
>   **1712** R.
>   STEELE Spectator No. 306. 6, I could
>   not keep my Eyes off of her.
>   **1720** D.
>   DEFOE Mem. Cavalier 281, I had
>   perswaded him off of that.
>   **1748** S.
>   RICHARDSON Clarissa V. xiii. 132
>   Biting my lip, [was to indicate] Get
>   off of that, as fast as possible.
>   **1775**
>   P. OLIVER in T. Hutchinson's Diary 7
>   Dec. I. 581 A Rebell
>   Pirate..taken..off of Cape Ann.
>   **a1805**
>   in F. J. Child Eng. & Sc. Pop. Ballads
>   (1894) V. IX. 106/2 Aff o the weather
>   [read wether] he took the skin, An
>   rowt his bonny lady in.
>   **1824** J. WIGHT
>   Mornings at Bow St. 21 Two young
>   men..were charged by a watchman with
>   having ‘bother'd him on his bate,’ and
>   refused to ‘go along off of it when he
>   tould 'em.’
>   **1843** T. C. HALIBURTON
>   Attaché 1st Ser. II. xii. 210 The
>   groom has stole her oats, forgot to
>   give her water, and let her make a
>   supper sometimes off of her nasty,
>   mouldy, filthy beddin'.
>   **1868** HARTLEY
>   Clock Alm. in Leeds Mercury Weekly
>   Suppl. (1895) 5 Oct., He connot
>   forshame To lift up his een off o' th'
>   graand.
>   **1875** P. BROOKS New Starts in
>   Life viii. 129 If you could have
>   filled his pockets with gold, and
>   feasted his hunger off of silver
>   dishes.
>   **1884** ‘M. TWAIN’ Adventures
>   Huckleberry Finn vi. 45 I'd borrow two
>   or three dollars off of the judge for
>   him.
>   **1909** G. GREIG Mains's Wooin' 6
>   He's swallowed the dictionar', min,
>   an's tryin' to get 'er aff o's
>   stammack.
>   **a1922** T. S. ELIOT Waste Land
>   Drafts (1971) 5 The reputation the
>   place gets, off of a few barflies.
>   **1962** F. NORMAN Guntz i. 15, I got hold
>   of this very very old typewriter off
>   of a friend of mine.
>   **1974** J. STUBBS
>   Painted Face xxiii. 284 Get off of me,
>   will you, sir?
>   **1990** B. ROCHE Poor
>   Beast in Rain II. i. 44, I was hangin'
>   around here all the time, gettin'
>   sweet nothin' off of you.

This may perhaps be more common in American English nowadays, but it certainly didn't originate there.

Comment: All but the most recent were prior to the creation of English dictionaries and grammar guides, comparing modern and historical English as if they have the same rules in not correct: clearly you can see the spelling of 'sponfull', 'perswaded',  'connot' is wrong and many examples are colloquial speech with abbreviated or colloquial words like *hangin'*,  *min* (mine),  *tryin*'. Only T. S.  Eliot is an example which is not speech and fairly recently (almost 100 years old).

Comment: this does not answer the question, it only points out the mistake is common

Comment: @Mousey English is not regulated. If it is in wide use for a long time then it potentially becomes correct.

Answer (score 5):

*Off of* does sound barbarous to the speaker of British received pronunciations but it's common (in every sene of the word) in regional dialects such as Cockney.

Perhaps grammar is a tribal mark of affiliation rather like the choice of vocabulary as in for example "toilet" vs "lavatory".

Answer (score 2):

> Or is there perhaps some simple way I can explain this to most people?

Yes, by explaining that the word *of* in that context, is unnecessary. It is superfluous. An unnecessary added extra. It is surplus to requirements. It adds nothing to the meaning of sentences.

Comment: *of* is a redundant word in the sentence - replacing *of* with *off* is correct, replacing *off* with *of* is clearly incorrect as well

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer? It is an Americanism similar to saying "Don't forget to write me" (American) as opposed to "Don't forget to write to me" (everywhere else).

Comment: Is it really an Americanism? Or is "off" a Britishism? After all, American English, by way of number of speakers, is standard English. (I'm British, btw)

Comment: I can see where you're coming from but I'd have to say that whatever came first is the original and anything after is an -ism. (I'm Australian and speak the Queen's English ;))

Comment: Contemporary British English is *not* "the original". And whatever the original was, it is no longer contemporary. Both American and British English have been deviating from their common ancestor — in different directions but by the same degree. And in many respects, contemporary American English is in fact much closer to the original than contemporary British English.

Comment: Contemporary British English is _not_ "the original"! No, we Brits have pinched (sorry, loaned) from the Greeks, the Romans, the Anglo-Saxons, the Normans ... Perhaps we need to mug up on Beaker-speak to determine what we should actually label **correct** English.

Comment: @soutarm Forsooth! What is this barbarous tongue that thou speakest and fain call by the name of "original English"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, perhaps you meant to write "borrowed" instead of loaned?  We didn't loan any words *from* the Greeks, et al.  And I do wonder at the term *borrow* in this context, because we don't ever intend to give them back, lol!  Perhaps *incorporated from* would be a better phrase?  Or even more likely, I'm overthinking it.  Since Herb has borrowed many items from Dagwood and still has them after all these years, maybe *borrowed* is, after all, appropriate.  Hmmmm.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I was verbing the _loan_ part of loan-word.  I thought 'pinched' and 'Beaker-speak' would show that the comment is tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I actually understood this -- my comment was trying to be tongue-in-cheek, too.  Perhaps I should have included a smiley emoticon?  :-)  What, by the way, is Beaker-speak?

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I'm not being tricked again. Find some other mug to tell you. :-)

Comment: @RegDwigнt You say: *And in many respects, contemporary American English is in fact much closer to the original than contemporary British English*. This is becoming such a widely repeated assertion that there is actually a danger that some people may start to believe it. Can you point to any work of scholarship which demonstrates that this be the case? If you can I will gladly read and consider it.

Comment: @OneProton Not true. On your definition, Indian English is the standard variety.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are approximately 125 Million English speakers in India... 225,000 consider English their first language. There are approximately 300 Million English Speakers in North America. So, I guess Indian English is also more standard than British English (Scotland, Ireland, England, Wales) as well. Fun fact. There are more native portuguese speakers both Brazil and in Angola than Portugal... meaning the home of Portuguese is in South America, Africa, and then Portugal.

Comment: @OneProton Sadly, you're stuck in 2001. The 125m figure was expected to quadruple within some ten-year period. The population of the USA is less than 500 million.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you have a current number, then? Or just guesses? The BBC article you're quoting from stating an estimate of 125m was written in 2012. However, if the Indian subcontinent has surpassed North American English... Indian English would indeed be the standard definition... to be honest, though I see India developing its own English/Hindi cross. The home of a language is where the most speakers of that language exist. As they live in isolation, they become new languages. Native English speakers today can't read & understand Beowolf, written in Old English. Twas a Different language

Comment: According to the estimates given in [this 2005 India Human Development Survey mentioned in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English), it seems that 22% of adults spoke English. Say 15% of the population. So that would be a rise of about 25m in 4 years. I've no other figures, but one can probably assume an increasing rate of growth (the US hasn't the population for this). There are real fears that Indian variants might sway accepted usages worldwide.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, if you mean to say, "off of", then you should instead say, "from". For example, "Take the book off of the bookcase", when, "Take the book from the bookcase", is preferable.
As I understand it, the expression "off of", is an Americanism, but the pseudo-antonym, "on of", is rarely (if not never), found in any language as far as I am aware.

Comment: Perhaps "on of" is never heard because there is a well established semi-antonym, _onto_.

Comment: "Get off of that roof!" should not be changed into "Get from that roof!" Maybe "Get down from that roof!"

Comment: Or perhaps it should be "off from". "Get off from that roof"

Comment: 'off' which indicates direction would need to be replaced with a direction word,  like 'down', but *Get off that roof!* is clearly correct. *Get of that roof* is clearly incorrect,  showing that *off* rather than *of* is the eseential and meaningful word in the sentence.