# Trying to make sense of (off?) "off of"

Tags: phrases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I explain to people that the phrase “off of” is grammatically incorrect?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect)

Is it just me or has the word combination "off of", and it's big brother "off of it", gained a certain prominence recently? People *jump off of [something]*, they find a business model and *make money off of it*, you can *eat off of it* and some people request to *keep your hands off of it* (whatever *if* refers to, then). Intuitively, I'd rather *jump off a chair*, I'd *make money of it*, I'd *eat off my plate* and of course, I'd *keep my hands off it*.

So, please tell me: What kind of language is this? Is it the latest fashion, is it the street language, or is it the way the educated ones talk? Or has this feature existed since ages, and I just didn't notice it yet?