# "Bite off" and "bite of"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrasal-verbs

"I take a bite off my pizza."
Or
"I take a bite of my pizza."
Or neither or both?
I am not sure how to use bite off/of correctly.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on [ell.se], especially as you call yourself a 'Novice'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited for ELL.

Comment: What can ELL do with a NARQ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a NARQ -- there's no question per se. 

Comment: There is a question and it's associated with english usage. I don't really understand putting this question or similar on hold while a simple answer can be much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I understand :

I took a bite of my pizza = I had a mouthful of a piece taken from my pizza (perhaps just cut off with a knife).

I took a bite off my pizza = I had a mouthful, biting the pizza with my teeth.

(I put the sentences in the past, since it is not easy to speak with your mouth full.)

Answer (score 0):

The correct phrasing is:

> I take a bite of my pizza.

You *can* say "take a bite off" but it means something different:

> Take a bite off that plate.

Comment: Many people regard the compound preposition _off of_ as non-standard English, and prefer either _off_ or _from_.

Comment: Interesting. Where I learned English it would be the exact opposite; "take a bit off that plate" sounds wrong to my ear.

Comment: I agree that _take a bit off that plate_ might be dubious (which is why I suggested _from_) but _off of_ is worse, to my ear. Would you balk at _He stepped off the platform_?

Comment: I would still prefer *stepped off of*. I found some interesting thoughts on the subject here on EL&U: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101683/difference-between-get-off-of-and-off

Comment: I edited the question to use "off" instead of "off of" because it seems the most globally acceptable.