# Using "on" before days or dates

Tags: word-usage, dates

I've noticed that on many American TV shows, the speakers generally don't use the word "on" before names of days or before dates.
For example: I'll see you Monday.

Shouldn't it be:

- I'll see you on Monday?
- The movie is coming out June 14th.

Is this usage exclusive to American English or this grammatically correct in British English as well?

Comment: In the UK, your second example would usually be: the *film* is coming out *on the 14th of* June. Dates in the UK are usually day, month and year.

Answer (score 1):

The drop of "on" is usual in British English too. Alexander, Longman English Grammar, § 8.12 says: In everyday speech "on" is often omitted:
- I'll see you Friday.
- See you June 21st.

One can say it is a general tendency of English that you can drop prepositions as long as the meaning remains clear.

Comment: And related to this, we can also say "throw something out the window" instead of "throw something out of the window". So, yeah, there's been a tendency to drop SOME prepositons when the meaning's clear.

Comment: This is typical of AmEnglish. In BrEnglish "to look out of the window" is still preferred.

Comment: But AmE seems to have more of a liking for 'inside of' than BrE.

Comment: Likewise [*off of* vs. *off*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101683).

Answer (score 0):

Omitting "on" is usual, using it is correct.

See you Friday - is usual

See you on Friday - is the correct way to go