# "Off the wall" vs. "Off of the wall"

Tags: prepositions

I used to think we should say "keep your hands off the wall", but one of the lines in Money, from Pink Floyd, they say "keep your hands off of my stash".
That made me confuse.

1. Do we always say keep your hands off *of*  something?
2. How does it work for "keep your hands off (of) the wall"?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How can I explain to people that the phrase “off of ” is grammatically incorrect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect)*; also see *[Difference between get “off of” and “off”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101683)* and *[“<verb> off of” expressions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132585/)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just *off* is correct, and should be used in a formal context. On the other hand, *off of* is quite popular, and usage dictates correctness in the long run. It's more common in American English than in British English.

I think it's popular because the pair *on - off* is similar in usage to *in - out*, and *out* goes with *of* in the same kind of sentences *off of* is used. E.g. *Get out of my house. Get off (of) the table.*

Answer (score 1):

The 'of' is superfluous, especially as 'of' is historically an unstressed form of 'off'.  It does seem to be popular in rock and pop songs, though: Mick Jagger sings "Hey, you, get off of my cloud!"

Comment: Do you have a source you can cite to show that "of" is an unstressed form of "off"?

Comment: @KristinaLopez Here's one that suggests that: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=of&searchmode=none

Comment: Thanks @Caleb!  David should include that in his answer - it was helpful!

Comment: I'd say that QOI has got it right, so I'll leave it that.