# 'Off of' versus 'from'

Tags: grammar, prepositions, british-english

Is 'off of' ever a valid substitution for 'from'? For example,

> 'It's that guy off of Friends.'

Would it ever be acceptable to use this construction in formal written English?

I live in the West Country (UK) and I hear this construction frequently.

Comment: You hear it everywhere, and it's becoming increasingly common among younger speakers. But I think most Brits who associate it with a geographical area would think it's more "American" than "West Country UK". As the original question shows, some people think it's ungrammatical - so if you want to avoid getting their backs up, it's best avoided in formal contexts. Unless you're prepared to "stand your ground" and defend it, which I personally would.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, quite. In relation to the duplication, wouldn't you agree that mine's the better question as it doesn't ask "why it's wrong"...

Comment: I'd be more inclined to say you are the better *questioner*, since you do at least acknowledge that the usage *may in fact* be "valid". Actually, I'm surprised so few people have answered/commented/voted on that original, but it's a [hardy perennial here on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-of) (as that link shows, we even have a tag specially for it).

Comment: It used to be _that bloke off the telly_ but it does seem to have morphed in to _that bloke off of the telly_ these days. But it only seems to work for some things _that bloke off of the German team ..._ doesn't work for me, _from_ works OK.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: despite being frowned upon in RP, "off of" has been used in the U.K. for many years. [See Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off+of+the+table%3Aeng_us_2012%2Coff+of+the+table%3A+eng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20of%20the%20table%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coff%20of%20the%20table%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) I have no idea what regions of the UK it was used in, but I wouldn't be surprised if it were West Country.

Comment: @Peter: But as your own NGram clearly shows, the usage has long been significantly more common in the US than the UK, *particularly* when we consider the last 2-3 decades (which is why I said it's becoming increasingly common among younger speakers). The possibility that this is a usage which "originated" in the West Country UK seems vanishingly unlikely to me.

Answer (score 2):

See the [discussion referenced by @FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect) for views on the general appropriateness of the term *off of*.

As to whether it can be substituted for *from* depends on context.

The term *off of* suggests that something is being obtained or moved.

> *I got that data off of the internet.*
>
> *They took the book off of the shelf.*

In these cases, *from* would be equally appropriate (and for many, preferable).

> *I got that data from the internet.*
>
> *They took the book from the shelf.*

When referencing something's place of origin, but not suggesting duplicating or moving, *from* can be used, but *off of* would sound off.

> *That character is from the Friends TV show.*

Comment: If you **get something *off* the table**, you’ve simply displaced it, like a dead bird that your cat dragged in.  “Get that off me!” On the other hand, if you **get something *off of* the table**, you’ve fetched something *from* that table.

Comment: @tchrist I do not disagree that *off* and *off of* may mean different things. And that *off* and *off of* are differentially related to *from*. I am not a fan of *off of*, in general, but seek to answer the question posed (accepting that some accept *off of*).

Comment: Everyone has their own language. I reported mine.