# Take it off of your shoulders

Tags: prepositions, off-of

I've stumbled across this sentence:  "I don't need your heavy load. Take it off of my shoulders".

I want to ask, is the usage of "take something off OF" correct?

Thank you in advance,
Matus

Comment: The allusion is to the Greek Titan Atlas, who supported the heavens on his shoulders (but is often depicted as supporting the world instead).  Hence the expression "weight of the world on your shoulders".

Comment: @Hot Licks: That's just a primitive myth. Most contemporary cosmologists agree that the world is supported by ***turtles*** 
(specifically, [*turtles all the way down*](https://cosmology.carnegiescience.edu/timeline/1610/turtles-all-the-way-down) :)

Comment: Besides the link added to the post  see [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect). The answers correct the idea of the title, which calls *off of* grammatically incorrect.