# Off-of Combination

Tags: phrasal-verbs, off-of

Not sure how to name this correctly, but there seems to be a trend of adding an "of" to phrasal verbs that ends in "off" and I'm wondering if that is, in fact, correct English.

Example from [here](https://www.geekculture.com/joyoftech/joyarchives/2810.html):

> I make a fortune off of them.

Shouldn't the correct usage be

> I make a fortune off them.

Comment: In American English *off of* (or “*offa*”) is common in speech. As one poster intimated at [How can I explain to people that the phrase “off of ” is grammatically incorrect?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect) — you gonna tell James Brown that “get up offa that thing” is wrong? On the other hand, if you’re writing a paper, omit needless words.

Comment: Oh, so it's American grammar… 

Answer (score 4):

This use goes back to the 15th century (and Shakespeare used it), but as the OED says of it "In later use colloquial (*nonstandard*) and *regional*".

So the "trend" of using it has been going on for more than six hundred years; but the trend of regarding it as "incorrect" only seems to go back one or two hundred.

Comment: So, it appears it would be correct to use it if I spoke Shakespearean English, but languages are living and I thought it changed away from it…unless the mummy returned. And just because it was used 600 years ago, it doesn't mean it's correct usage nowadays. So, is it only "regarded" as incorrect or is it in fact incorrect?

Comment: @AlexIxeras - 'So, is it only "regarded" as incorrect or is it in fact incorrect?' Is there a difference? How can one tell?

Comment: "Correct" is a social judgment, like wearing the "right" clothes or using the "right" fork for your dinner. Which set of fashion gurus do you wish to follow?

Comment: If I were to write my (English) sentences back to front or in Old English these days I could claim this to be correct for the 21st century, but it wouldn't be. There is some sort of agreed standard, I suppose. I agree that frequent general use by the general public could legitimise or elevate some expression but in my case here there is something that doesn't sound right to me. Maybe it's because English is a second language to me, but then again, us "ESL"ers often learnt it more textbook like.

Comment: @AlexIxeras There surely are things that are hard to call other than incorrect, eg "I'm making a fortune __of off__ them". But 'off of' is very idiomatic for me. I'm not a professional writer or editor, but I wouldn't bat an eye at 'off of' (though either 'off of' or 'off' is more characteristic of things being spoken rather than writing.

Comment: Citations and a clearer explanation might improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: _Off of_ is the conventional spelling of the frequent practice of adding an epenthetic central vowel (schwa /ə/) at the end of monosyllabic prepositions like _off_ and _out._ The zombie rule that forbids _off of_ but allows _out of_ is, like split infinitives and _It is I_, a product of upperclass English parsons with too much time on their hands and strange ideas about reforming the lower classes by correcting their speech. It's stupid and irrelevant, and should be ignored. Go right ahead and say and write _off of_ any time you want. It's your language, not Lindley Murray's.

Comment: While I agree with your comment in general, @JohnLawler, I think your characterisation of the expression as a phontic variant is wrong, at least for BrE. _I got it off of a friend_ is common in various parts of the UK, and the /v/ is definitely present.

Comment: Probly true; nuts and bolts get used every which way. But I've found it useful to keep an eye on epenthesis, like _If you hadna done that, theyda left_, which is normal speech, but doesn't have a good prose translation.

Comment: I can't quite follow why forbidding *off of* but allowing *out of* is a zombie rule, but leave that to the native speakers. In the example *I got this off of a friend* my understanding is that here the *off* is the same or similar to *from*, and we wouldn't say *I got this from of a friend*. – All this discussion makes me wonder if expressions like *off of* are regionally used. Despite that, *off of* sounds plain wrong to me, but we're also living in a time where words like *there* and *they're* is used liberally and almost interchangeably. One day those might become common and accepted too.

Comment: The answer @AlexIxeras is that language is what it is, not what somebody thinks it ought to be (whether for reasons of logic or anything else). Prepositions _from_, _off_, and _out of_ are standard (but _off_ is standard only in a spatial sense). Prepositions _out_, _off_ (in an extended sense) and  _off of_ are non-standard.